# Android - ImageButton onClick event fails to fire

Tags: android

I am developing an application where I dynamically populate the parent container `LinearLayout`  whith many other `LinearLayout` children, and each one of these children is gone be populated with many `ImageButton`, It is basically like this:

The XML code is:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/phasesContainer" (parent container)
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And the Java code:

```
  for (PhaseActor pa : ph.get_actors()) {
    if (pa.get_prospective() != Phase.PROGRAM)
                continue;
            ImageView phaseActor = new ImageView(context);
            phaseActor.setImageResource((int) getActorFromMemory(
                    pa.get_actroId()).get_iconId());
            phaseActor.setMaxHeight(30);
            phaseActor.setMaxWidth(30);
            phaseActor.setTag(pa.get_id());
            phaseActor.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);


            phaseActor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    editPhaseActorClick(Integer.getInteger(v.getTag()
                            .toString()));
                }
            });

 // This container is the child (LinearOut) container 
            container.addView(phaseActor, imageLayout);         }
```

When I click on the ImageView it doesn't not do anything.. the function doesn't get triggered!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

**phaseActor.setClickable( true );**

or you can use ImageButton instead of ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

You say ImageButton in your title but there is an ImageView in the code, are you sure you want to use an ImageView? Using an ImageButton should get you exactly what you need.